# Javascript variables appended in a string not getting replaced with it's original value

Tags: javascript, node.js

The string **''+notify_name+' likes your post.'** is coming from the database. We are storing this static string in the database.

variable **ntfnFound[0].body** contains this string that we fetched from the database.

```
var notify_name = 'tintu';

console.log(ntfnFound[0].body);   /* ''+notify_name+' likes your post.' */

var body = ntfnFound[0].body;

console.log(body);   /* ''+notify_name+' likes your post.' */

console.log(''+notify_name+' likes your post.');   /*tintu likes your post*/
```

My question is,

In the above code why not 'console.log(body);' displays 'tintu likes your post' ??

or

Why +notify_name+ is not getting replaced ??

Also is there any solution for converting the string in 'var body' to 'tintu likes your post' ??

IN the following code works,

```
console.log(''+notify_name+' likes your post.');   /*tintu likes your post*/
```

Comment: It sounds like you want to store a template in the db and then apply some data to that template when it's rendered?

Answer (score 1):

My first guess would be:
You saved the STRING in your DB, when pulling it out, it is still a String, so must likely the ' and + are escaped: \' and \+.

What you are trying to accomplish is to save a String in your DB where you later want to insert the value of your variable.

My approach would be: saving something like "{0} likes your post" and then use some kind of printf function on it.

have a look at : [JavaScript equivalent to printf/string.format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-equivalent-to-printf-string-format)

Comment: I`m getting an error against format() - undefined is not a function.

Comment: Format ist not a buildin Funktion in JS, you have to include a library or write your own. Like in the topic i linked: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4673436/3801048

Answer (score 0):

There are no automagic replacements in JS - you'll have to it yourself with  `body.replace("+notify_name+",notify_name);`.

The reason it worked in the log is. because JS did what you told it to do: '' is an empty string, then you catenated the name and the text 'likes your post'.